# Torso ID (No hands)

Tags: part-identification

[image]

What is the number of the piece and where does it come from?

Comment: Seriously? This is a Minifig torso, how would you not know where to use this? Or are you looking for all the sets this piece might have been in?

Comment: No The Number Of The Piece

Answer (score 6):

This is a [Torso Overalls Blue Pattern (Dungarees) / White Arms / Yellow Hands](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0201c01#T=S&O=%7B%7D), which is used in [48 sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973pb0201c01&in=S) and [16 minifigs](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973pb0201c01&in=M). It was last produced by LEGO in 2005.

I'd seriously recommend you make yourself familiar with BrickLink's Catalog Search feature and the LEGO naming standards as it helps you get these answers faster in the future, without having to rely on others on this forum to do the searching for you.

Comment: No I'm Just Trying To Find Out Who's This Is Is It A Mailmans Or Somebody Else's

Comment: This body piece was typically used for a construction worker (either male or female).

Comment: I would rather say it was typically used for mechanics people (repairing cars...) instead of construction workers.. ;)